# Hide element with JS from C# in Site.Master the elemet is appearing again after page refresh

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, master-pages, show-hide

I'm running this codebehind with c# in Site.Master.cs:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, Page.GetType(), "text", "myFunction()", true);
```

That code fires this script in my Site.Maste.ASPX:

```
<script>
        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("XXXX");
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
</script>
```

it supposed to hide this element:

```
<li ID="XXXX" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
```

I can see it hides for some miliseconds, but the page refresh inmediately and it appears again.
How can the item could keep hidden after page refresh?

Edit:
Thanks for your answer. After some hours of thinking and testing I got what I wanted with this:
I took the < li > out of the LoggedInTemplate so I can reach it from C# (I was unable to see the control from C# if it was inside the LoggedInTemplat, I dont know why ), well, then I just set visible-false with C# in Masterpage:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Autenticado");
                Aprobacionesbtn.Visible = true;    //button in the navbar
                Reportesmenu.Visible = true;    //dropdown menu in the navbar

            }

            else if ((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User == null))
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("No autenticado");
                Aprobacionesbtn.Visible = false;    //button in the navbar
                Reportesmenu.Visible = false;    //dropdown menu in the navbar
            }
        }
```

Comment: What event in page master are you using to inject that script? Page load and injection of the master page occurs first, then the child page THEN loads and runs. Explain what you mean by shows, and then hides. That CAN NOT occur all by it own self. If you at this point in time click on a button in child page. Then master page load event does trigger EACH and every time, but IsPostBack will be false at that point in time. If you do a response.redirect in that child page (or use master page menu bar navigation), then you are in a way starting over and IsPostBack=false for both master+child pages

Comment: It is running with a button in Master Page. But should I move to pageload? The button is just for testing if it works

Comment: yes, you need to re-inject that js code each time. On button click, then page load (master) triggers, then child page code runs. If any button is clicked on child page, then master page code runs page load event (but without the js injection), then child page load event runs, then child page button code runs.  You better off to use code behind in place of js code, and place that code in master page load, and use somecontrol.visible = false.

Comment: and yes, you should move the code to master page load event. See my posted example below as to "how" you can get at the menu bar controls from code behind.

Comment: Thank you. Now I'm applying a simply somecontrol.visible=false, it is working with some controls I have outside my < LoggedInTemplate >, but it is not working with the same controls with the same properties inside the LoggedInTemplate. A message with controlx does not exist appears.

Comment: Well, as I stated, we need to persit the values (use session). And the menu bar options will not take effect until you leave the logon page, but 99 out of 100 times, user will logon, and then you navigate to some page anyway, right, so it not going to be any kind of issue I can think of. So, user will not see the changes in master page by you changing the persisted values (session I assume??).  this also suggests that such controls by default should be hidden in that master page load event. So, I suppose this suggests that you check for session value, or is nothing, and that hides the control.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, we need some example code

user q:

> I cant fint controls from masterpage's codebehind

Well, unless the controls are marked as runat = server, and furthermore, unless the controls in question have a "id", then we kind of missing two things we need here!!

So, say I have a menu bar (master page).

I want to hide (or show) somthing things, say maybe based on their logon rights (say what roles they belong to).

So, add some "id" and "runat" server tags to ANY of the buttons you want to hide/show/control.

So, you don't have to add "id" and runat="server" to "everything", but just those few controls (menu options) you need/want to control.

So, say this menu bar:

```
<li id="m10" runat="server"><a id="A2" runat="server" 
    href="~/Contractors/Flipper" 
    title="Change company you are working with">Change Company</a></li>

<li id="mAdmin" runat="server" class="dropdown"  ClientIDMode="Static">
    <a runat="server"  href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Site Admin<span class="caret"></span></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/SiteAdmin/Messages">Manage Portal Email Messages</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Staff/CurrentUsersS">Show Logged on users</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/SiteAdmin/OneMonth">Month Logon Summary</a></li>

    <li><a runat="server" href="~/SiteAdmin/EditChoices">Change/Edit Issue tracker choices</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/SiteAdmin/SetUp">Developer site settings</a></li>
    <li><a onclick="hasproof()">My Proofs - testing</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/SiteAdmin/Issues">Issues Tracker and to-do list</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

the first li (list item) is a menu bar - contractor. If the user logged on is NOT a contractor, then I hide that menu item.

the next item is a WHOLE drop down list. That drop down menu item is only for "site" admins.

So, code behind, on master page load is this:

```
Me.mAdmin.Visible = Roles.IsUserInRole("SiteAdmin")
Me.m10.Visible = Roles.IsUserInRole("Contractor")
```

so, based on users role membership, if they are a member of the SiteAdmin group, then visible = true

Same goes for contractors - again it is a rather simple matter to hide/show the menu item(s).

so, you WILL HAVE to persist these values, and set them EVERY TIME on page load in master.

And the reason is that when you use the master page menu bar, and navigate to a whole new page (url), then the page is 100% re-loaded, and thus any settings you make will be lost.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. After some hours of thinking and testing I got what I wanted with this:
I took the < li > out of the LoggedInTemplate so I can reach it from C# (I was unable to see the control from C# if it was inside the LoggedInTemplat, I dont know why ), well, then I just set visible-false with C# in Masterpage:

Comment: ```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if ((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Autenticado");
                Aprobacionesbtn.Visible = true;    //button in the navbar
                Reportesmenu.Visible = true;    //dropdown menu in the navbar

            }
```

Comment: ```
            else if ((System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User == null))
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("No autenticado");
                Aprobacionesbtn.Visible = false;    //button in the navbar
                Reportesmenu.Visible = true;    //dropdown menu in the navbar
            }
        }
```